# Counting problem

Tags: self-study

Suppose I have 5 distinctly numbered balls that I have to distribute in 3 pails. All 5 must be placed in the pails. In how many ways can this be done?

I think I'm missing a counting trick here that I am unaware of, like weeks ago when I learned that there was such a thing as !n thanks to this site (thanks!). Or maybe my brain is just too tired already as I've been doing this the entire day.

Comment: Are the balls distinguishable?

Comment: Yes. Each is uniquely numbered.

Comment: Just consider the first ball. How many ways can you place ball 1? Now, does that first ball affect how many ways you can place ball 2 (/which placements count as distinct)? (hint: if it's not clear, write down all the ways of placing two balls) ... Now consider the same question in relation to the next ball

Comment: Putting five balls into pails named $a,b,c$ can be done by expanding the polynomial $(a+b+c)^5$. (Do that for smaller exponents, like $2$ and $3$, if this isn't perfectly obvious.) The expansion sums terms of the form $n(i,j,k)a^ib^jc^k$ where $i+j+k=5$. Such a term corresponds to $i$ balls in pail $a$, $j$ balls in pail $b$, and $k$ balls in pail $c$. The coefficient $n(i,j,k)$ counts the number of ways that can happen. To obtain the total number of ways you could sum all the $n(i,j,k)$, but there is indeed a trick: the sum is obtained by setting $a=b=c=1$, so the answer is $(1+1+1)^5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first ball may be placed into three different pails. 3 choices

The second ball may be placed into three different pails without regard to the location of the first ball. So with the current ball, there's 3 distinct choices *for each placement of earlier balls*.

(... and so forth).

---

... alternatively, think of the problem flipped about to an equivalent problem. Instead of placing the ball into a pail, lay the balls out in order and put a sticky note on each one with the pail it's assigned to (which we could label 0,1,2).

Looking at the balls sitting in a row, you now you have a 5 digit number in base 3 . . .

Comment: I like the first one better. So it's $3^5$?

Comment: We try to offer "hints and guidance" on routine bookwork questions (of the sort that might be set for [homework](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), for example). So I won't actually be giving the explicit answer, just some ways to approach the problem - if anything I've given a bit more detail than I really ought.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I just commented that your first explanation was more intuitive for me than the second. I asked if my answer was correct just to make sure that I understood correctly.

Comment: I wasn't commenting on your preference for the first explanation; different explanations appeal to different people, and that's fine. I was responding to the question at the end, by way of explaining why I wasn't going to respond to it, since it would amount to specifically answering a self-study question.

Comment: I apologize if my question was out of line. It's just that from a pedagogical perspective, it helps a lot when a student knows that his understanding is correct by means of knowing that it produces the correct answer. This allows him to have confidence in applying the same reasoning to other problems. However, I do get that this site should not be providing answers to assigned classwork to students. In my case however, this is not assigned classwork. Of course, I know that there is no way to verify that and I understand that the rules prohibit giving exact answers to self-study questions.

Comment: There's no need to apologize. I definitely understand the desire to ask. I'd suggest looking at 3 balls and two pails and writing out all the possibilities ($[123|\cdot],[12|3],[13|2],[23|1],[1|23],[2|13],[3|12],[\cdot|123]$). Then look at 4 balls and two pails and at 3 balls and 3 pails (those can all be listed out in reasonable time). You'll soon see if you have understood it.